# IntelliJ Java Gui Doesn't add JTextField

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

My problem is IntelliJ IDE doesn't add `JTextField` here is the code.

```java
public IntellJ (){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(400,600);
        frame.setLocation(400,200);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        setContentPane(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(panel);


        JLabel jLabel1=new JLabel("Ogrenci Numaraniz");      
        JTextField jText=new JTextField("Hi");

        jLabel1.setBounds(20,20,150,50);

        jLabel3.setBounds(20,70,150,50);
        panel.add(jLabel1);       
        panel.add(jText);
    }
```

If I'm delete JTextField and try `JLabel jText = new JLabel("Hi");` write this code is working. I don't understand why `JTextField` is being problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem in your program is that you try to use absolute positioning of components (using `panel.setLayout(null)` and using `setBounds()` on components). Instead, always use layout managers in Swing UIs.

Also, call `frame.setVisible(true)` at the end, after setting up all UI components.

I've done these changes to your code and it works:
(Here I have simply removed `setLayout(null)`. So, the default layout managers are in action.)

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class IntellJ {

  public IntellJ (){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(400,600);
    frame.setLocation(400,200);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);

    JLabel jLabel1=new JLabel("Ogrenci Numaraniz");
    JTextField jText=new JTextField("Hi");

    panel.add(jLabel1);
    panel.add(jText);

    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new IntellJ();
  }
}
```